# Windows 2003 Web Edition & Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, web

I'm tackling a project with 3-4 developers, and I want them to work all on the same machine through Remote Desktop. Thus I'm currently looking for an economically priced dedicated server that will fit my needs.

My question is, whether the Web Edition of Windows 2003 server allows multiple users concurrently to log into the machine through remote desktop to work with the applications installed there?

On Wikipedia i read that remote desktop is available in this edition for "administration purposes".

Answer (score 2):

No. Terminal services has two modes, application and administration. Administration mode allows 2 users concurrently out of the box, application mode will require terminal services licensing. This goes for any edition of Windows Server.

Comment: Thank you! so the smallest version that supports multiple users will be the standard edition? if there are not more than 2 users concurrently, web edition will work also or are there further limitations regarding remote desktop work?

Answer (score 0):

All editions of Window Server 2003/2008 (with the exception of web edition) work the same and have the same capabilities in regards to RDP sessions. You can have 2 RDP sessions when the server does not have the TS (RDS) role installed and you can have as many RDP sessions as you have TS (RDS) licenses when the TS (RDS) role is installed.

With web edition you only get 2 RDP sessions for remote administration.